# Trouble with UDP Client

Tags: java

I am having trouble sending data between a UDP Server and Client, I am trying to ,send an array of strings to the client from the server. The loop that I am using will hang up and stop reading the data from the server. If i pick a small number for the loop everything is okay it works but if I try to transmit the whole string it will stop half way and the client freezes up. Here is the server it reads a file and then sends the data to the client using a loop.

````
     ```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UDPServer1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        int portNumber=9999;        

        UDPConnection com1 = null;

        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
        Message MS1 = new Message();
        char x = 0;
        int m = 12, c=0;
        double q;
        int percent=20;      
        String[]  message = new String[255];
        String m1;
        x = (char)m;
        m1 = x + "";        //turn next page character into string
        double rand = Math.random();
        //String ACK="";


        System.out.println("Enter the percentage of packet losses will happen in the transmission: ");
        //percent = MS1.getInt();

        DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket(portNumber);

        File infile = new File("COSC635_P2_DataSent.txt"); 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(infile); 

        // we just need to use next page as delimiter
        sc.useDelimiter(m1); 

        while(sc.hasNext() )        //get data packets
        {
            message[c] = sc.next()+m1;
            c++;
        }       

        System.out.println("UDP server Started ");

        byte[] data = new byte[6500];
        DatagramPacket receivedFrame = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        ds.receive(receivedFrame);
        String ACK = new String(receivedFrame.getData(),0, receivedFrame.getLength());
        //str = message[80];
        //receiveData(ds);
        //com1.setPort(receivedFrame.getPort());
        portNumber = receivedFrame.getPort();
        byte[] frame;                   
        //dp1;
        //System.out.println("Dp port is " + dp.getPort());
        int i = 0;
        while( i<=c-1)  //error control goes here
        {
            //frame = (message[i].trim() ).getBytes();
            //ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();   
            //DatagramPacket sendFrame= new DatagramPacket(frame, frame.length, ipAddress, receivedFrame.getPort());            
            sendData(ds, message[i].trim()+ACK+ " port number is " + portNumber, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber);

            //ds.receive(receivedFrame); 
            //ACK = receiveData(ds);            

            //simulate lost packets
            //rand = Math.random();
            //q = rand*100;
            //if(percent < (int)q)
                //ds.send(sendFrame);
                i++;
        }
        //frame = ("End of File").getBytes();           
        //ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();               
        //sendFrame= new DatagramPacket(frame, frame.length, ipAddress, receivedFrame.getPort());
        //ds.send(sendFrame);           
        ds.close();
    }

    static String receiveData(DatagramSocket socket) throws IOException
    {
        byte buffer[];
        buffer = new byte[6500];        
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);
        String received = new String(packet.getData(), 1, packet.getLength() - 1).trim();
        System.out.println(received);
        return received;        
    }

    static void sendData(DatagramSocket ds, String data, InetAddress ipAddress, int portNumber) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] frame = null;        
        frame = (data.trim() ).getBytes();
        DatagramPacket dp1= new DatagramPacket(frame, frame.length, ipAddress, portNumber);

        //simulate lost packets
        //rand = Math.random();
        //q = rand*100;
        //if(percent < (int)q)
        ds.send(dp1);
    }
}      

```
````

Here is the code for the client.

````
```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class UDPClient 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {      
        DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
        String  fileContent ="";
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        int socketNumber=9999;
        byte[] ACK = null;      
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("COSC635_P2_DataRecieved.txt");
        System.out.println("UDP Client Started");
        String mess = "";

        Message m1;
        //send frames 
        //Frame is the string
        ACK = (" ").getBytes();     
        DatagramPacket dp= new DatagramPacket(ACK, ACK.length, ipAddress, socketNumber);
        dsocket.send(dp);

        byte[] data = new byte[6500];
        String str = "";

        DatagramPacket dp1 = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        dsocket.receive(dp1);
        str = new String(dp1.getData());

        int i =0;
        while( i<70)    //error control needs to go here
        {
            //ds.receive(dp1);
            //str = new String(dp1.getData(), 1, dp1.getLength() - 1).trim();       
            mess = receiveData(dsocket);
            //mess = mess + " i is " + i;
            System.out.println( mess.trim());
            System.out.println( "inside loop");
            //fileContent = fileContent + mess;
            i++;
            sendData(dsocket, "Packet Received " + i + " ", ipAddress, i);
        }
        //
            //System.out.println(fileContent);
            System.out.println("outside loop");
            fileWriter.write(fileContent);
            fileWriter.close();
            dsocket.close();
            System.out.println("data socket closed");

    }

    static String receiveData(DatagramSocket socket) throws IOException
    {
        byte buffer[];
        buffer = new byte[6500];        
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);
        String received = new String(packet.getData(), 1, packet.getLength() - 1).trim();
        System.out.println(received);
        return received;        
    }

    static void sendData(DatagramSocket ds, String data, InetAddress ipAddress, int portNumber) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] frame = null;        
        frame = (data.trim() ).getBytes();
        DatagramPacket dp1= new DatagramPacket(frame, frame.length, ipAddress, portNumber);     
        ds.send(dp1);
    }

}

```
````